# Change PowerPoint settings for slide show primary monitor

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Is it possible to set the Monitor in the Slide Show tab from Automatic to Primary?

Is there a registry key associated with that setting?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide more information? Are there 2 monitors?

For the Office with version number is 16.0, such as Office 2019, you may go to Registry Editor, locate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerPoint\Options`, add a dword value, the value name "UseAutoMonSelection", the value data is 0, which is for Primary Monitor.

But, if you change the Monintor in PowerPoint, value data would follow the change.

[image]